# How to solve the problem in double probability?

Tags: probability

**My problem**:Of the fifteen flights operated by the airline during the day, 60%
operated by our own fleet. Find the probability that the selected
out of 5 random flights, exactly 3 are operated by our own fleet

**My attempts to solve this problem**:First, I found the number of flights from **60%** using the proportion that are carried out by our own fleet - **9**. After that, I try to understand which formula to apply in this case, because in this task there is a double probability

Comment: Hint: binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really about a kind of double probability. You just have to go on your way. If $9$ flights are operated by our own fleet, then $6(=15-9)$ flights are operated by another airline. So you have two groups of flights (elements). And you select 5 elements without replacement where 3 elements belong to the group with 9 elements and $2(=5-3)$ elements belong to the other group with $6$ elements. In this case you apply the hypergeometric distribution [[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). Thus the probability that the selected out of $5$ random flights, exactly $3$ are operated by our own fleet is

$$P(X=3)=\frac{\binom{9}{3}\cdot \binom{15-9}{5-3}}{\binom{15}{5}}=\frac{\binom{9}{3}\cdot \binom{6}{2}}{\binom{15}{5}}=0.42=42\%$$

(*rounded to 2 decimal places*)